# server application wildfly(jboss)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans-8, server-application

Hi everyone I search in forum and google but I don't have response.
When I run server application Wildfly(Jboss) I have this error:

Deploying on WildFly Application Server
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Starting WildFly Application Server
WildFly Application Server Start Failed. HTTP Connector port 8080 is already in use.

thanks for hepl.

Comment: So check your ports if there is something running on `:8080` or change the wildfly port. You can use this CMD command `netstat -an | find ":8080"`    -   Maybe you got some other server running by default and you forgot about it. Happens to me because of XAMPP stuff, too.

Comment: If the port is unused when the server is stoppepd, then remove your `war`, `ear`, ... from it and start it normaly. If this does work - paste your build-goal here. Jboss can does run `redploy` automatical if there is something with same name, but I don´t know about wildfly. Glassfish for example need `:deploy` first time and then other goal for `:redeploy` - glassfish su**s.^^

Comment: I try your propositions but I don't resolve my problem

Comment: So there was nothing Running on the Port and nothing deployed?

Comment: TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [java.exe]

Comment: When your server is turned on it´s correct - when the servis is off you need to have a look on other applications/servers running on java. Normaly there will be no output if nothing running on the port.